# Escaping new line characters

Tags: c#, outlook, newline, icalendar

I'm trying to create an outlook calendar event but part of my text disappears in outlook.

```
private List<ICalEvent> _events;

public override void ExecuteResult(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext context)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    var _with1 = str;

    foreach (var _event in _events)
    {
        _with1.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        _with1.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
        _with1.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
        _with1.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0}", _event.start.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z")));
        _with1.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0}", _event.end.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMdd\\THHmmss\\Z")));
        _with1.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", _event.summary));
        _with1.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", _event.description));
        _with1.AppendLine(string.Format("LOCATION:{0}", _event.location));
        _with1.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        _with1.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
    }

    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
    context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "newFile"));
    context.HttpContext.Response.Write(str.ToString());
}
```

The problem occurs when I have multiple lines in the `description`. If it contains the text **"New\r\nLine"** for example I will only get "New" in my outlook calendar description. The part after **"\r\n"** disappears.

I've tried all these but with the same result:

- `_event.description.Replace("\r\n", "\n\n")`
- `_event.description.Replace("\\", "\\\\")`
- `_event.description.Replace("\r\n", Environment.NewLine)`

Anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: try to use _event.description.Replace("\r\n","<br/>")

Comment: @Frank59 That will print "New<br/>Line" and not actually give a new line in Outlook.

Comment: same problem here http://forums.asp.net/t/956883.aspx/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write '=0D=0A' at the end of your lines.

Comment: Thank you! I also needed this for it to work: **"DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:"**

Comment: what is `=0D=0A` ??